# TreeView not expanding for child nodes. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I have created a TreePanel that uses a TreeStore and a Model that originally was not showing labels.  I added a Column to the panel and the labels of the tree showed.

I don't get errors for adding grandchildren to the tree but the tree won't expand or show the grandchildren

```
Ext.define('Writer.view.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

    itemId: 'mainView',
    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    region: 'center',
                    itemId: 'contentPanel',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'card'
                    },
                    title: 'Content',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'htmleditor',
                            height: 150
                        }
                    ],
                    dockedItems: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'toolbar',
                            dock: 'top',
                            width: 400,
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    text: 'MyButton',
                                    listeners: {
                                        click: {
                                            fn: me.onButtonClick,
                                            scope: me
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    text: 'MyButton'
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    text: 'MyButton'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'treepanel',
                    region: 'west',
                    id: 'projectTree',
                    itemId: 'projectTree',
                    width: 150,
                    title: 'Organizer',
                    store: 'MyTreeStore',
                    viewConfig: {
                        rootVisible: false,
                        listeners: {
                            select: {
                                fn: me.onViewSelect,
                                scope: me
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'treecolumn',
                            width: 148,
                            defaultWidth: 149,
                            enableColumnHide: false,
                            dataIndex: 'name'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {

        // This Works
        var tree = Ext.getCmp('projectTree');

        var treeNode = Ext.getCmp('projectTree').getRootNode();
        treeNode.expandChildren(true); // Optional: To see what happens
        treeNode.appendChild({
            name: 'Child 4',
            leaf: true
        });

        // This one works
        treeNode.childNodes[1].appendChild({
            text: 'Grand Child 3',
            leaf: true
        });

        treeNode.childNodes[1].expand();
    },

    onViewSelect: function(dataviewmodel, record, eOpts) {

    }

});
```

I am going crazy trying to figure it out.  I also made JSON for the store that now had grandchildren and it all loads in fine but once again it fails to show them in the tree.

```
{
    "success": true, 
    "Root": [
          {
            "name": "Chapters",
            "leaf": true,
            "expanded": true,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Chapter 1",
                    "leaf": true,
                    "expanded": true
                 },{
                    "name": "Chapter 2",
                    "leaf": true,
                    "expanded": true
                 },{
                    "name": "Chapter 3",
                    "leaf": true,
                    "expanded": true
                 }
            ]
         },{
            "name": "Characters",
            "leaf": true,
            "expanded": true
         },{
            "name": "Settings",
            "leaf": true,
            "expanded": true
         }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `leaf` means?

Comment: I did not, but after looking it up I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Evan's comment; and from: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-cfg-leaf

> Set **leaf** config to true to indicate that this child can have no children. The
>   expand icon/arrow will then not be rendered for this node.

So in your case, remove `leaf: true` config from any node that has children and you want to expand them.

As I've said before in your previous questions, I highly suggest you read the Sencha documents first, not only it can answers most of your common questions, but reading it will also make you understand the basics logic before implementing, so you won't have to ask a simple question in the future.

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking at the docs as I have been playing with it.  I try to Google the issues I run into first and also refer to the docs. I didn't know there was a limit on the kind of question that could be asked here or what is considered simple to you, maybe not others, but thanks for the help

Comment: @ThinkNewDev Let me rephrase my sentence: "Reading documents can save you lots of precious time :)" I didn't say anything about "question kind limit"

Comment: I understand, but reading documentation does not always explain everything... like for instance setting leaf to true for only the grandchildren now makes my json load in recursively and killing the page... no errors just crazy loading lol

Comment: Better yet, don't just copy and paste code you don't understand. If you don't know what `leaf` does, go look it up.

Comment: To be clear I wasn't just copying and pasting code.  I was doing a lot of reading and looking up as I was building.  Most examples I saw had the lead element.  Had I looked up that element specifically? No, but excuse me for trying to learn and using a site like this for its intended purpose.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli if you don't want to answer or provide anything useful, you could simply ignore and let someone else answer. No one is forcing you into my question, or perhaps you lack the ability to keep from making snide remarks?  I just started with ExtJS and Sencha Architect two days ago with the trial and trying to get up to speed quickly.  It's not entirely for lack of understanding or just copying code and hoping for the best.  I have been reading the docs and Googling everything.  I see on your  profile you work for Sencha. Is this how you go about getting all your customers?

Comment: @ThinkNewDev well if you have another problem, ask away. I will try my best to help you :)

Comment: Not being snide at all. In the comment, I hinted at how you can go about finding the answer. In my second, I suggested that you not copy bits without knowing what they do. How is that being snide? Of course it's going to cause you problems if you're using options without knowing what they do.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Yeah and if you read my comments I responded to what you said about leaf and looked it up. Clearly I was pulling from examples I found online as I was trying to learn. Unless you somehow failed to read my response to your initial comment, jumping in again with saying something about just copying and pasting code I don't understand was entirely unnecessarily.  You do know what snide means right?  Go ahead and look it up if you don't understand.